# Cannot reach some devices from different Subnet

Tags: networking, kvm

I am a little bit confused about my network setup at home.

This is the setup:

VLAN1 - 172.16.20.0/24
VLAN2 - 10.11.12.0/24

I am in the VLAN2 net (which is my WiFi), for the moment I allowed all traffic between both subnets.

My setup uses a KVM host for most of the services, my firewall lies on this machine and is virtualized (opnsense).

So the KVM network interfaces looks like this:

```
ip a show ens1f0 
4: ens1f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1b:78:5c:e8:20 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.20.100/24 brd 172.16.20.255 scope global noprefixroute ens1f0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

This is a dedicated NIC for the management only! No bridges or other stuff here.

```
[root@kvmhost ~]# ip a show ens1f1
5: ens1f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1b:78:5c:e8:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

This NIC is directly connected to my DSL modem for the dial up connection and is directly attached through KVM

Additionally there are 2 more NICs which are acting as network bridges for virtual machines (those are tagged for the VLANs)

Okay, I got a few machines in the 172.16.20.0/24 net, and I can reach them all from the other subnet (10.11.12.0/24)

I can ping them, access https, ssh whatever.

What I can't reach is the management IP of the KVM host, I saw something's going on with tcpdump:

I tried a curl from my machine to the KVMs host management web interface (which is cockpit)

```
curl -Ik https://172.16.20.100:9090
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.16.20.100 port 9090: Operation timed out
```

tcpdump on the kvm host gives me this:

```
[root@kvmhost ~]# tcpdump port 9090
dropped privs to tcpdump
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on LAN, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
19:06:27.090325 IP 10.11.12.30.50317 > kvmhost.mylocaldomain.de.websm: Flags [S], seq 4181416652, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3155175134 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
19:06:28.095233 IP 10.11.12.30.50317 > kvmhost.mylocaldomain.de.websm: Flags [S], seq 4181416652, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3155176134 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
19:06:29.097152 IP 10.11.12.30.50317 > kvmhost.mylocaldomain.de.websm: Flags [S], seq 4181416652, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3155177134 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
19:06:30.102374 IP 10.11.12.30.50317 > kvmhost.mylocaldomain.de.websm: Flags [S], seq 4181416652, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3155178134 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
19:06:31.109466 IP 10.11.12.30.50317 > kvmhost.mylocaldomain.de.websm: Flags [S], seq 4181416652, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3155179134 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
19:06:32.194191 IP 10.11.12.30.50317 > kvmhost.mylocaldomain.de.websm: Flags [S], seq 4181416652, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3155180134 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
19:06:34.203560 IP 10.11.12.30.50317 > kvmhost.mylocaldomain.de.websm: Flags [S], seq 4181416652, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3155182134 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
19:06:38.231893 IP 10.11.12.30.50317 > kvmhost.mylocaldomain.de.websm: Flags [S], seq 4181416652, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3155186135 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
19:06:46.278145 IP 10.11.12.30.50317 > kvmhost.mylocaldomain.de.websm: Flags [S], seq 4181416652, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3155194135 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
19:07:02.377538 IP 10.11.12.30.50317 > kvmhost.mylocaldomain.de.websm: Flags [S], seq 4181416652, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3155210135 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
19:07:34.614607 IP 10.11.12.30.50317 > kvmhost.mylocaldomain.de.websm: Flags [S], seq 4181416652, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,eol], length 0
```

I am not a network professional, but I think that some traffic arrives here but I do not get anything back.

I even tried to ping directly from the subnets (10.11.12.1) gateway to the host (opnsense got some good debugging tools) but even that does not give me anything

As I am not a professional in networking stuff I researched alot in the web but was not able to really find a solution.

My thought is that I got something like a network loop here?!

As I said I am able to reach any other machine running on the kvm host which are in the same subnet ...

I am able to reach the machine when I am on the same network of course.
As opnsense automatically creates routes between interfaces/subnets on the same firewall I do not need to add routing manually.

Any hints where to look at?

Thx

Dan

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it by myself.
The management interface itself was missing a route to the VLAN2 net.
Works now :)